# I get an error splicing file on nautilus when trying to copy it (4.7GB) to a USB FAT32 memory stick

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, avidemux

I get an error splicing file (the message said nothing else) on Nautilus when trying to copy it (4.7GB mp4 file) to a USB FAT32 memory stick: I'm using FAT32 because my dumb tv demands it. I gather that there's a 4GB limit on a FAT32 file. What's the best method of separating it into say 2 files?
PS avidemux 2.7qt won't play the file (though vlc can) or save the first half of the file: it gives muxer:cannot open popup.

Comment: file sizes greater than 4GB cannot be copied into the filesystem as it's tooo big for fat32.  try using exfat filesystem instead.

Comment: You could also compress the file to make it smaller than 4GB.

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve the problem is to use `ffmpeg` to create two files. Start by checking the total duration of the video, and then create one video clip for the first half and one video clip for the second half.

I tested with a small file with duration 19 seconds and split it at **10** seconds:

```
ffmpeg -t 10 -i 00007_720-50p.mp4 -c copy xaa.mp4
ffmpeg -ss 10 -i 00007_720-50p.mp4 -c copy xab.mp4
```

This can be played in Ubuntu by

```
vlc xaa.mp4 xab.mp4
```

and I hope also by your TV.

You can find explanations of the options in `man ffmpeg`

---

An alternative is to let `ffmpeg` write a copy encoded with a slightly lower quality, so that the size will be small enough (slightly below 4 Gibibyte). But this process will be much slower than to let it simply copy the streams.

---

If the TV can read from an exFAT file system you need not split the file.